# Using malloc in C to allocate space for a typedef'd type

Tags: c, malloc, typedef, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm not sure exactly what I need to use as an argument to `malloc` to allocate space in the `table_allocate(int)` function. I was thinking just `count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof(count_table*))`, but that doesn't do anything with the size parameter.  Am I supposed to allocate space for the `list_node_t` also?  Below is what I am working with.

In the .h file I'm given this signature:

```
//create a count table struct and allocate space for it                         
//return it as a pointer                                                        
count_table_t* table_allocate(int);
```

Here are the structs that I'm supposed to use:

```
typedef struct list_node list_node_t;

struct list_node {
  char *key;
  int value;

  //the next node in the list                                                   
  list_node_t *next;
};

typedef struct count_table count_table_t;

struct count_table {
  int size;
  //an array of list_node pointers                                              
  list_node_t **list_array;
};
```

Comment: You've got quite a few good answers, but no one yet has noted an important point: `int` is a signed type, and unless you want to have negative sizes, you should use `size_t`, which is the type returned by the `sizeof` operator and passed to `malloc` and friends, and is intended to be able to store the array index for arrays of any size allowed by the compiler. You probably want `size_t size` instead of `int size`.

Answer (score 8):

```
count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof(count_table*))
```

is wrong. It should be

```
count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof(count_table));
```

Also, you must allocate memory for list_node_t also seperately.

EDIT:

Apart from what Clifford has pointed about allocating memory for the list node, I think the memory allocation should also be taken care for the `char *key` inside of the list node.

Comment: so in the function I should probably malloc the count_table and then malloc space for the list_node_t and then put that list node inside the count_table?  Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes. You are getting this right. : ) But, please refer to Clifford's answer about your double pointer usage for list_node_t. You need to check why is it given as a double pointer there. Thanks!

Comment: +1 but I would write `count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof *cTable);` personally.

Comment: @Chris Lutz & Clifford, I do agree with your ideas about this. But, also many a times I have seen people make a typo error and miss the '*' thereby causing only 4 bytes to be allocated. This problem leads to troubles hard to find in a big code. So, am a little confused about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion: `count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof(count_table*))` would only allocate space for a *pointer* to a count_table.

You'd need

```
count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof(count_table) ) ;
```

Each list node would be separately allocated and cTable->size and cTable->list_array and the last `list_node_t::next` updated accordingly.  Maintaining a pointer to the last node added would make adding nodes faster.

I am not sure why `count_table::list_array` is of type `list_node_t**` rather than just `list_node_t*`  (and equally called `list_array` rather than just `list`).  Is it your intention that it is both an array and a list at the same time?  That would be somewhat redundant.  The member need only be a pointer to the first node, successive nodes are then accessed via `list_node::next`

Comment: @detley:  No I mean :: because the left-hand-side is a type not an instance.  I am using C++ scope notation, though it is not intended that this is code, I am simply using it as a notation to refer to a member of a struct rather than member of an instance of a struct.  There is no syntactic way of doing that in C.

Comment: what you are saying makes a lot of sense. as for the (int size) parameter... do you think it is intended that I add that many nodes to the count_table in that function?  I don't understand what the size parameter is for.

Comment: I think the idea is that there is an array of lists, so that when a node is hashed, you look in the relevant array entry, then trundle down a singly linked list.  That at least makes sense of the data structures.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: That sounds likely.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `int` is a "size" parameter for the created `count_table_t`, it appears that you are supposed to both allocate the `count_table_t` itself, as well as initialise its members.

Initialising the `list_array` member also involves a memory allocation, so it would look like:

```
count_table_t *table_allocate(int size)
{
    count_table_t *table = malloc(sizeof *table);
    int i;

    table->size = size;
    table->list_array = malloc(size * sizeof table->list_array[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        table->list_array[i] = NULL;

    return table;
}
```

However, you also need to check for some error conditions: the multiplication of `size` by `sizeof table->list_array[0]` could overflow, and either of the `malloc()` calls could fail.  So the function should actually look like this:

```
count_table_t *table_allocate(int size)
{
    count_table_t *table;
    int i;

    /* Check for overflow in list allocation size */
    if (size < 0 || size > (size_t)-1 / sizeof table->list_array[0])
        return NULL;

    table = malloc(sizeof *table);

    if (table == NULL)
        return NULL;

    table->size = size;
    table->list_array = malloc(size * sizeof table->list_array[0]);

    if (table->list_array == NULL) {
        free(table);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        table->list_array[i] = NULL;

    return table;
}
```

(Note that `(size_t)-1` is a constant equal to the *maximum* value of a `size_t`, which is the type of the parameter to `malloc()`).

Comment: Note also that the OP's `int count`s should all probably be `size_t`s.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Agreed (and that would remove the need for the `< 0` check), but it sounds like the function signature and `struct` definition were handed-down requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other posters who point out that you're only allocating enough space for the pointer, not the space the data you want will occupy, I strongly urge you to do things like this:

```
count_table* cTable = malloc(sizeof(*cTable));
```

This will help you in case the type of `cTable` ever changes, you won't have to adjust two parts to that line, just the type.