# Pointer changes at runtime

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, cygwin, malloc

I have the following file `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LEXER_INC(l) ( (l)->pos++ )

#define isCidstart(c) (isalpha(c) || (c)=='_')
#define isCident(c) (isalnum(c) || (c)=='_')

typedef struct LexerState
{
    const char *fileName;
    const char *sourceText;
    int sourceLength;
    const char *pos;
    const char *end;
    int line;
} LexerState;

typedef enum LexerToken
{
    TokenHalt,
    TokenPush,
    TokenPop,
    TokenEndOfLine,
    TokenEOF,
    TokenNone
} LexerToken;

typedef struct ReservedWord
{
    const char *word;
    LexerToken token;
} ReservedWord;

static ReservedWord reservedWords[] =
{
    {"halt", TokenHalt},
    {"push", TokenPush},
    {"pop", TokenPop}
};

void lexerInit(LexerState *lexer)
{
    lexer->fileName = "test.s";
    lexer->sourceText = "pop\r\npush\r\nhalt\r\n"; // read from file
    lexer->sourceLength = strlen(lexer->sourceText); // 17
    lexer->pos = lexer->sourceText; // pointing to first char of lexer->sourceText
    lexer->end = lexer->sourceText + lexer->sourceLength; // end of lexer->sourceText string, i.e. '\0'
    lexer->line = 1;
}

LexerToken lexerCheckReservedWord(const char *word)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < (sizeof(reservedWords) / sizeof(ReservedWord)); count++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(word, reservedWords[count].word))
            return reservedWords[count].token;
    }

    return TokenNone;
}

LexerToken lexerGetWord(LexerState *lexer)
{
    const char *startPos = lexer->pos;
    LexerToken token = TokenNone;
    char *word;
    int len;

    do
    {
        LEXER_INC(lexer);
    }
    while (lexer->pos != lexer->end && isCident(*lexer->pos));

    len = lexer->pos - startPos;
    word = malloc(len + 1); /* (len + 1) for '\0' ending */
    strncpy(word, startPos, len);
    word[len] = '\0';

    token = lexerCheckReservedWord(word);

    return token;
}

LexerToken lexerGetToken(LexerState *lexer)
{
    char thisChar;

    /* Skip white characters */
    while (lexer->pos != lexer->end && isspace(*lexer->pos))
    {
        if (*lexer->pos == '\n')
        {
            /* New line found */
            lexer->line++;
            LEXER_INC(lexer);
            return TokenEndOfLine;
        }

        LEXER_INC(lexer);
    }

    if (lexer->pos == lexer->end || *lexer->pos == '\0')
    {
        return TokenEOF;
    }

    thisChar = *lexer->pos;

    if (isCidstart(thisChar))
    {
        return lexerGetWord(lexer);
    }

    return TokenEOF;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    LexerState *lexer;
    LexerToken token;

    lexer = malloc(sizeof(lexer));
    lexerInit(lexer);

    while ((token = lexerGetToken(lexer)) != TokenEOF)
    {
        printf("token %d\n", token);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When debugging with `gdb` the function `lexerGetWord`, I realised that after executing the line `word = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));`, the `lexer->pos` pointer address changes to some number (in my case `0x23`):

```
82              len = lexer->pos - startPos;
(gdb) next
83              word = malloc(len + 1);   // (len + 1) for '\0' ending
(gdb) print len
$1 = 3
(gdb) print lexer->pos
$2 = 0x60003b1b3 "\r\npush\r\nhalt\r\n"
```

Here `lexer->pos` points to this address after getting word `"pop"` from the string `lexer->sourceText` (`"pop\r\npush\r\nhalt\r\n"`)

```
(gdb) next
84              strncpy(word, startPos, len);
(gdb) print lexer->pos
$3 = 0x23 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x23>
```

But after `malloc` is executed, the pointer changes it address, resulting later in `Segmentation fault`.

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ ./test
token 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This only happens with Cygwin gcc. I tried MinGW and **all works fine**.

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.3 Stepan 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Comment: Is there an actual problem with the code? What you observe in `gdb` might be a result of optimization and not really be a problem. If there is a problem, then please post a [mcve]

Comment: Run your code with something like `valgrind` - it'll flag up any memory related issues which are often the cause of the problems you're seeing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I disabled all optimization and it still doesn't work

Comment: Disabling optimizations is not really disabling *all* of them.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't copy the `'\0'` at the end of the string if it is not in the copied length. In your case the chars `pop` are copied, but the string isn't closed. Add `word[len]='\0'`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner, thanks I'll try

Comment: @EugeneSh. Anything else I could do?

Comment: @Frankie_C, well you're right, but the problem itself is before `strncpy` call.

Comment: MCVE as I already asked.

Comment: as for the `strncpy()` issue your problem should be a distraction error, because formally the code you showed seems correct. The only interaction between the `malloc()` and the pointer corruption could be related to reuse of free memory or the like. In plain words from what you showed us no clue is visible. Chek again **all your code flow**.

Comment: @Frankie_C, thanks, updated the post.

Comment: @EugeneSh., done MCVE, updated the post.

Comment: One problem - `lexerGetWord` will always return `TokenNone` (is it intentional?). And will leak some memory as you allocate `word` and then loose it.

Comment: @EugeneSh., updated the post. I posted more code, maybe that helps.

Comment: Well, you've got the answer down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `main`:

```
lexer = malloc(sizeof(lexer));
```

You're allocating enough space for the *pointer*, not what it points to.  As a result, you end up writing past the end of allocated memory.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need space for what `lexer` points to:

```
lexer = malloc(sizeof(*lexer));
```

Comment: As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252271/8269790) my code is correct.

Comment: @StepanKlymonchuk It is **not** correct.  In the linked answer, the type name is given.  In your case, a variable name is given, and that variable has type `LexerState  *`.

Comment: No, it is not. `lexer` is a pointer. In that answer `count_table` is a `struct` (a type name)

Comment: @StepanKlymonchuk Undefined behavior.  One of the ways that manifests itself is that things appear to work properly, then something as simple as recompiling can cause it to crash.